# Freemarker how to select checkboxes on UI send by backend?

Tags: html, spring-boot, user-interface, checkbox, freemarker

Have following data passed from backend:

```
ALL_CONFIGS: {callDigitalIo=true, controllerId=1, numberPlatesHashSalt=..., numberPlatesShouldBeHashed=false, parkingStatusShouldBeChecked=true}
```

Where ***boolean params*** should be displayed like `input` element with `type=checkbox`.

Here is how I handle it on UI page (`.ftl`):

```
<div>
    <label class="col-form-label">
        Parking Status Should Be Checked:
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-2"
               id="parkingStatusShouldBeChecked" name="parkingStatusShouldBeChecked"
               <#if parkingStatusShouldBeChecked??>checked="checked"</#if>
        />
    </label>
</div>
```

However, checkboxes are all selected:

[image]

`Number Plates Should be Hashed` should not be selected.

***How to select only `true` variables?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After huge research I found solution for this issue:

```
<div>
    <label class="col-form-label">
        Parking Status Should Be Checked:
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-2"
               id="parkingStatusShouldBeChecked"
               <#if parkingStatusShouldBeChecked == "true">checked</#if>
        />
    </label>
</div>
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `parkingStatusShouldBeChecked` is a boolean, this way works too:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input ml-2"
           id="parkingStatusShouldBeChecked" name="parkingStatusShouldBeChecked"
           ${parkingStatusShouldBeChecked?string('checked','')} />
```

The first parameter is the "true" expression, so FreeMarker prints `checked`. Otherwise it prints just an empty string.

See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_string_for_boolean